# What's the difference between "Richtungssinn" and "Richtung"?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I was studying Physics(Statik) and I saw the word *Richtungssinn*. It translates as "sense of direction". And I know Richtung is "direction". But what does *sense of direction* even mean?

DE: Ich übe Statik und ich habe der Begriff "Richtungssinn" gelesen. Ich weiß, dass Richtung "direction" bedeutet, aber ich habe "Richtungssinn" nicht klar verstanden.
Zum Beispiel, gibt es hier einen Text in meinem Buch. Es handelt vom Parallelogrammsatz für Kräfte. Es erklärt eine alternative Lösung für das Problem.

"Einfacher ist es, die Kräfte nach Betrag und Richtungssinn maßstabsgerecht in beliebiger Reihenfolge aneinander zu setzen."

Wenn hier nicht Richtungssinn geschrieben wäre, sondern Richtung, wie könnte man die Bedeutung unterscheiden?

Im also new here, sorry if I made any grammatical mistakes or wrong writing format.

Comment: welcome to German.SE. Just for the "completioness" of your context - could you please add the situation, where "einfacher ist es..." refers to?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm completeness.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Thank you.  I just wrote, hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a technical term (obviously). You can just translate it as direction. In statics, you distinguish the *Wirkungslinie* (the straight line on which the force takes effect) and the *Richtungssinn* (the direction on this line).

Answer (score 8):

[Richtungssinn](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richtungssinn) ist in diesem Kontext ein physikalischer Fachbegriff (Definition siehe [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statik_starrer_K%C3%B6rper#Kraft), ähnlich zu Drehsinn/Drehrichtung), im Alltagsgebrauch würde man immer einfach *Richtung* sagen.

Die weitere Bedeutung  (ähnlich zu *Orientierungssinn*, also die Fähigkeit, eine Richtung beizubehalten) ist hier nicht relevant.

Comment: Sehr gute Erklärung, als Link schlage ich https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statik_starrer_K%C3%B6rper#Kraft vor (Abschnitt *Kraft*).